# RVM: Uninstalling all gems of a gemset

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have global gems and various gemsets. I want to remove all gems of a gemset. Is there a way do to this, besides uninstalling the gemset?

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Use the `gemset empty` command:

```
rvm gemset empty mygems
```

Comment: You need to specify the gemset you want to empty. It's not enough just to "rvm use [gemset_name]". You need to "rvm gemset empty [gemset_name]".

Comment: I suppose if you have many gems, it could take a while to uninstall them all.

Comment: Incidentally right now I am able to run `rvm gemset empty` and it clears the current gemset.

Answer (score 17):

This command removes all the ruby gems installed locally in 1-step
Works well in Ubuntu 10.10

```
gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx
```

PS - removes all local gems. Use sudo accordingly.

Comment: gem also has a --no-versions flag, which is nice:

`gem list --no-versions | xargs gem uninstall -aIx`

Answer (score 13):

you can also use `rvm --force gemset empty`

Answer (score 12):

`rvm gemset empty <gemset name>`

This will remove all gems from your mentioned gemset.

Answer (score 6):

`rvm gemset empty <gemset>` works, but only if you specify a gemset name.

If you want to empty the *default* gemset, you need to pass an empty string for the gemset name.

`rvm gemset empty mygems ""`

Answer (score 4):

Isn't removing all the gems out of a gemset essentially the same operation as deleting a gemset and then adding it back? Why not just do this:

```
$ rvm gemset mygemset
$ rvm gemset delete mygemset
$ rvm gemset create mygemset
```

Comment: Yes, essentially it's the same. But I was wondering if there is a way to do this without deleting the gemset. When you delete a gemset, are the gems removed too or are they saved to a cache?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're completely removed. For example, I have a gemset named `jruby-1.5.6@radiant`. All the gems are located here: `/Users/dparoulek/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.6@radiant`. When I do `rvm gemset radiant`, then it warns you to make sure, and then deletes the entire `/Users/dparoulek/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.6@radiant` directory.

Comment: This would be about the same I guess. I was looking for an alternative because I wanted to remove all the gems from the global gemset so that I could stop new gemsets from "inheriting" the gems from the global gemset.

Answer (score 2):

This is the safest way to uninstalling all gems of a gemset

**Step 1**

If you gem version is less then 2.1.

```
gem update --system

gem --version
```

**Step 2**

```
gem uninstall --all
```

[**references**](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-uninstall-all-ruby-gems/)