# Uninitialized constant error message after a typo done while installing devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, devise, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just started learning how to program, but have been using Ubuntu for some years now, so I am well familiar with researching problems and errors, but either this area is too new for me, or I really cant find any specific answers for this.

I am taking a ruby on rails introduction course, and got to the point where I had to install the devise gem and here is where I made a mistake.

While following the instructions on [the devise github page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) I accidentally typed in:

```
rails generate devise install
```

instead of

```
rails generate devise:install
```

Now, whenever I try to load

> rails s

I get this error message:

```
/home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant Install (NameError)
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise.rb:256:in `get'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise.rb:290:in `new'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise.rb:290:in `add_mapping'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:208:in `block in devise_for'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `each'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `devise_for'
from /home/amer/Documents/Rails_Projects/omrails/omrails1/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
from /home/amer/Documents/Rails_Projects/omrails/omrails1/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/amer/Documents/Rails_Projects/omrails/omrails1/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/amer/Documents/Rails_Projects/omrails/omrails1/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /home/amer/Documents/Rails_Projects/omrails/omrails1/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /home/amer/Documents/Rails_Projects/omrails/omrails1/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Before posting here I tried reinstalling ruby 1.9.3. using rvm. I tried using

```
rvm gemset empty [gemset_name]
```

as was discribed in [RVM: Uninstalling all gems of a gemset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693445/rvm-uninstalling-all-gems-of-a-gemset) but that didn't really help either.

What should I do? Can anyone explain to me what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood your problem.
You have written `rails generate devise install`. It means that you have associated `install` as a model to devise rather configure it. So your files have been created with out devise configuration.

You just follow what I have written:
1) Create a **`devise.rb`** file in **'/config/initializers'** 
2) Write the following code inside it:

`Devise.setup do |config|`
    `config.mailer_sender = "devise@example.com"`

    `config.scoped_views = true`
  `require 'devise/orm/active_record'`**#[This works for you]**
  `config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]`
  `config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]`
  `config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]`
  `config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10`
  `config.reconfirmable = true`
  `config.reset_password_within = 6.hours`
  `config.sign_out_via = :delete`
 `end`

2) And write **`rails destroy devise install`** in the terminal. Thats it.

I think the above will work for sure.

3) Now start your server again **`rails s`**. 
4) Install devise again carefully. And go ahead.

Comment: Hey! @VenkatK thanks for your answer. I followed your steps, but when I ran `rails destroy devise install` i had what appears to me to be the same error message again.

Starting with `/home/amer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant Install (NameError)` and so on.

Comment: @user1861553 If that is the case again, better removing those files which were created when running `rails destroy devise install` manually. And restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a gem problem, just a confused Devise setup, which is likely easily unconfused.

When you run the Devise generator (with `rails generate Devise:something`) it runs code to create a few files specific to your application within your application tree (app/*).  I am looking at a Devise install and think it's mostly going to be in the `app/views/devise` directory, but it's possible that it also updates your User model.  It definitely updates your `app/routes.rb` file and creates a file in `config/initializers`.  There may be others.

Delete any of these. There may be other files in locales, db/migrate (there is a migration -- don't run it, or run `rake db:rollback` before deleting it if you have).

Then re-run the installation.

Another approach if this doesn't work would be to create a new dummy Rails app, install devise there, and see what files get created -- usually generators report what they are doing.

Comment: none of those files exist, and it doesn't seem to have changed anything is routes.rb.

when i run the ' rake db:rollback' command I get an ininitialised constant devise error.

Comment: OK, well I think it's likely that *something* within your Rails app that has been installed by Devise is causing the problem.  A close examination of the stack trace suggests either `environment.rb` or `routes.rb` or perhaps a file in the `initializers` directory has been created.  @VenkatK may be right that the first incorrect run has attempted to associated Devise with the non-existant model Install, but in any case, you should just remove anything (including the reference to the devise gem from the `Gemfile.rb`) from your app.  This is a great use for source control :-)