# No implicit conversion of nil into string devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am new to ruby. I am simply attempting to set up Devise. I am following the instructions at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise and when I get to the `rake db:migrate` command, it tells me the rake is aborted and there is "no implicit conversion of nil into String". It's frustrating since I am doing exactly what the guide/videos are doing and I get an error.

See error below.

```
User$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
no implicit conversion of nil into String
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:24:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:24:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:24:in `sqlite3_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:863:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not certain, so I don't want to suggest this as an answer, but it seems like it could be that you haven't created the database or the connection information in `config/database.yml` isn't present/accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely due to a bad `config/database.yml` file. Here is a regular one:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is exactly what is in the config/database.yml and it still isn't working

Comment: can you please show us which version of devise you are using ?

Comment: Just tried with a dummy project using devise 3.0.0 and rails 4 it works fine. Try to add `bundle exec` before `rake db:migrate`

Comment: That gave me a massive wall of text and says I may have encountered a bug.. is that normal?

Comment: not really... you may want to try reinstalling all your gems... I using RVM, this is easy here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693445/rvm-uninstalling-all-gems-of-a-gemset

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same problem, which was caused by the following line in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.mailer_sender = 'no-reply@' + Rails.application.secrets.domain_name
```

`Rails.application.secrets.domain_name`, which is defined in `secrets.yml` is not set, which was the cause of the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

Rake was giving me this message every time I tried `rake install`-ing a gem.  It would successfully package the gem, then try to run `ruby -S gem install pkg/my_gem.version.gem`.  It would fail.

Weird thing was, running the command from the command line would successfully install the same gem.

Seeing someone else suggest that all the gems should be reinstalled, I tried just reinstalling the rake gem.  It seems to have fixed it.  (I also reinstalled the bundler gem, but I don't believe that was the problem).